# Magento 2 : Ajax call in Checkout shooting error 500 / 503

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, ajax

I am integrating In-store pickup in Magento 2 checkout page. I have called one ajax while check page is loaded and append all stores with the In-store shipping method.

The JS file:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
    ], function($) {
        url = $('.url').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: url+'pickupshipping/index',
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#checkout-shipping-method-load').after('<div class="store_selectbox" style="display:none">'+data+'</div>');
        });

    $(document).on('click', '.table-checkout-shipping-method .row' ,function() {
        var sel_val = $('.all_stores').val();

        if ($('#s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping').is(':checked')) {
            instockcheck(sel_val);
            $('.store_selectbox').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $('.store_selectbox').css('display', 'none');
            $('#in-store-address-display').html('');
            $('#checkout-step-shipping').removeClass('sealed-content');
            $('#display-error').html('');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#shipping-method-buttons-container button', function(e){
        if ($('#s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping').is(':checked')) {
            var sel_val = $('.all_stores').val();
            var receive_later = [];
            var receive_asap = [];
            var remove_p = [];
            $('.remove_p').each(function(index, val){
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    remove_p.push($(this).parent().find('.each_pro').val());
                }
            });
            $('.receive_asap').each(function(index, val){
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    receive_asap.push($(this).parent().find('.each_pro').val());
                }
            });
            $('.receive_later').each(function(index, val){
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    receive_later.push($(this).parent().find('.each_pro').val());
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                data: {choose_store: sel_val, remove_p: remove_p, receive_asap: receive_asap, receive_later, receive_later},
                type: 'post',
                url: url+'pickupshipping/index/checkoutnext',
            }).done(function (data) {
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('change', '.all_stores', function() {
        var sel_val = $('.all_stores').val();
        instockcheck(sel_val);
    });

    function instockcheck(sel_val) {
        $.ajax({
            data: {choose_store: sel_val},
            type: 'post',
            url: url+'pickupshipping/index/checkoutinstockcheck',
        }).done(function (data) {
            if(data != 'success') {
                url1 = window.location.href+'cart';
                button_url = '<a href="'+url1+'">Goto Cart</a>';
                if ($('#s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#display-error').html(data+button_url);
                    instoredisplay(sel_val);
                }

            } else {
                $('#display-error').html('');
                if ($('#s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping').is(':checked')) {
                    instoredisplay(sel_val);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function instoredisplay(sel_val) {
        $.post(url+'pickupshipping/index/getshopdetails', {choose_store: sel_val}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            $('#in-store-address-display').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

This Ajax is called when choosing In-store shipping:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Pickupshipping\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
//use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as session;

class Checkoutinstockcheck extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $product_not_instock = array();
        $shop_code = $this->getRequest()->getParam('choose_store');
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
                // retrieve quote items collection
        $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
                // get array of all items what can be display directly
        $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $index = 0;
        if(!empty($itemsCollection)) {
            foreach($itemsCollection as $each_item) {
                $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($each_item->getProductId());

                $inStore = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($shop_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

                if($_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle') {
                    continue;
                }

                if(empty($inStore) || $inStore < 0) {
                    $product_not_instock[$index]['product_name'] = $_product->getName();
                    $product_not_instock[$index++]['id'] = $each_item->getProductId();
                }
            }
        }

        $msg = 'success';
        if(!empty($product_not_instock)) {
            $msg = '<div class="alert-msg-instock">Following product is not available in-store: <br/><ul>';
            foreach($product_not_instock as $each_p) {
                $action_html = '<div>
                                    <div>The quantity requested for this item exceeds the selected stores inventory.</div><br/>
                                    <div>Please select one of the following options:</div><br/>
                                    <div class="pro_container">
                                        Action Required: (Please check the box)<br/>
                                        <input type="radio" name="checkout_options_'.$each_p['id'].'" class="receive_later" value="1" />Allow an additional 0-5 days to pick up my entire order<br/>
                                        <input type="radio" name="checkout_options_'.$each_p['id'].'" class="receive_asap" value="2" />I would like to receive my items seperately as soon as the become available.<br/>
                                        <input type="radio" name="checkout_options_'.$each_p['id'].'" class="remove_p" value="3" />Remove this item from my order<br/>
                                        <input type="hidden" class="each_pro" value="'.$each_p['id'].'" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                $msg .= '<li><div class="preduct_name" style="color:#000"><b>'.$each_p['product_name'].'</b></div>
                            <div>'.$action_html.'</div>
                         </li>';
            }
            $msg .= '</ul></div>';
        }


        echo $msg;
        return;
    }
}
```

> **But the Ajax call is giving 500 error.**
>
> Can anyone tell me what is the reason ?

Comment: try changing  your url variable name to       `customUrl = $('.url').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: customUrl+'pickupshipping/index',`

Comment: Done, still getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. Magento checkout contains a several number of ajax call and js loading. Sometimes my ajax returns success data but "#checkout-shipping-method-load" field was not loading due to which my next ajax data field was blank sometimes, now I have fixed the issue by changing little in coding.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had almost the same issue on community.magento.com and I have added a solution there.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Show-custom-payment-method-error/m-p/58533#M1564

Comment: Thank you, but this have not resolved my problem. I am getting 500 error when calling the ajax.

Comment: I understand but you can see the actual error in the Network Tab in the Chrome Inspector.

Comment: I have checked and it is showing 500 server error. Is this due to any coding issue in ajax calling or ajax file? or server side issue? and how to overcome this?

Comment: I understand that it is the status code but have you also clicked on the request and take a look at the response?

Comment: I found the issue was in page loading, so ajax  data field was blank and throwing 500 error. Now I have fixed the issue. Thanks.